# gradle run task on external project

Tags: gradle, groovy

Let's say I have two independent projects:

```
./
  |
  +- projectA
  |  |
  |  + build.gradle
  |  + settings.gradle
  |  + gradlew
  |  + .gradle/
  |  + gradle/
  |  + submodulea/
  |
  +- projectB
     |
     + build.gradle
     + settings.gradle
     + gradlew
     + .gradle/
     + gradle/
     + submoduleb/
```

I'd lile to execute certain tasks for `:projectB:submoduleb` from the buildscript of `:submoduleA`. For example:

**projectB/submoduleb/build.gradle**:

```
//...
task test() {
    println 'hello from :projectB:submoduleb'
}
//...
```

How do I call `test` from **projectA/build.gradle** ?

Comment: As `projectA` and `projectB`are unrelated, you can't. Define a root project enclosing `projectA` and `projectB`

Comment: I think "you can't" is plain incorrect. Perhaps the term you're looking for is "you're not supposed to". @ToYonos

Answer (score 2):

You can use a task of the type [`GradleBuild`](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.GradleBuild.html) to invoke an external Gradle project. Just specify the project directory of the other project and the tasks you want to execute:

```
task myTask(type: GradleBuild) {
    dir = file('path/to/other/project')
    tasks = ['test']
}
```

Unfortunately, this task type does not provide more than the pure task execution, e.g. it is not possible to retrieve feedback from the task.

If your setup requires any more features like the above, you could add some kind of coupling between the projects (multi-project build, composite build) or write your own custom solution.

Comment: Moreoever, the op said *I'd lile to execute certain tasks for :projectB:submoduleb from the **buildscript** of :submoduleA*. Even more complicated

Answer (score -1):

You don't *call* tasks in Gradle. the tasks to run, and their order, are determined automatically based on the command line used to invoke Gradle.

If you want a task in submodleb's build to always run before or with a certain set of tasks in submodulea's build, you can use task dependencies.

**E.g. projectA/build.gradle**

```
build.dependsOn ':projectB:test'

task myTask() {
    dependsOn ':projectB:myProjectBTask'
}
```

With this build script, calling `gradle projectA:build` will run the `test` task in projectB, then the `build` task in projectA. Similarly, calling `gradle projectA:myTask` will run `myProjectBTask` first.

Comment: That's not always an option, and stating that 'You don't call tasks in Gradle' is generally incorrect. You can `project(":module").tasks.sometask.execute()`

Comment: Also, you don't show the configuration of how you add external project `:projectB` which is pretty much the main part of the question

Comment: From https://discuss.gradle.org/t/how-can-i-call-a-task-from-another-task-with-dependencies/5961, for example: "Calling ‘execute()’ on tasks is not supported at all."

Comment: Apologies, I missed the fact that the projects didn't share a common super-project.

Comment: You should **NEVER** call `execute()` on tasks!